# Default return value for JPA query

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT SUM(total_price) FROM ... WHERE ...", nativeQuery = true)
```

which works as expected when there are matching records. But when there are no matching records, the query returns `null`.

How can I return zero(`0`) instead of `null` when no records are found?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change return type to be an `Optional`;

```
@Query(value = "SELECT SUM(total_price) FROM ... WHERE ...", nativeQuery = true)
Optional<Integer> getSum(...);
```

Or you can wrap this `getSum()` with a `default` method;

```
@Query(..)
Integer getSum(...);

default Integer safeGetSum(..) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(getSum(..)).orElse(0);
}
```

More info on [*null handling in repositories*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.nullability)

---

When the return value is not a list, or some wrapper (plus some others check below), & there are no matching records, the return will be null, so there is no *slick* way to handle this with some `defaultValue=0` through `@Query`

> The absence of a query result is then indicated by returning null. Repository methods returning collections, collection alternatives, wrappers, and streams are guaranteed never to return null but rather the corresponding empty representation.

Comment: Very elegant usage of both `Optional` and `default`.

Answer (score 5):

A native SQL option is [`COALESCE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617) which returns the first non-null expression in the arg list

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(total_price),0) FROM ...
```

Comment: Even though a solution, adding any extra logic, however simple, on native queries should be evaded. Query should be as simple and to-the-point as possible. JPA has very nice support for null check already, which is both more readable & more maintainable IMO

Comment: I agree the the OPTION is a better solution. Just adding it here for completeness.